# c# regex to parse columns in a txt file

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a text file looks like this

```
FieldA    FieldB    FieldC    FieldD  FieldE
  001       中文                15%     语言
  002       法文      20        12%     外文 
  003       英文      21                外文
  004     西班牙语               10%     外文
```

so basically I have the file read in and split into lines. Now I would like to use regex to split each line into fields. As you can see some fields in the column are actually empty, the fields may not in fixed width, but is separated by at least one white space. Some fields contains Chinese characters.

May I know how to do this? Thanks.

Comment: How, do you know that 外文 goes to column FieldE, not to FieldD?

Comment: that is the thing, i need the regex to know that there are 5 fields. but last fieldE is confirmed to be chinese, while FieldD is percent or empty.

Comment: What are the fields separated with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string s = "001       中文                15%     语言";
Match m = Regex.Match(s, 
    @"(?<A>\d*)\s*" +       // Field A: any number of digits
    @"(?<B>\p{L}*)\s*" +    // Field B: any number of letters
    @"(?<C>\d*)\s+" +       // Field C: any number of digits
    @"(?<D>(\d+%)?)\s*" +   // Field D: one or more digits followed by '%', or nothing
    @"(?<E>\p{L}*)");       // Field E: any number of letters
string fieldA = m.Groups["A"].Value;    // "001"
string fieldB = m.Groups["B"].Value;    // "中文"
string fieldC = m.Groups["C"].Value;    // ""
string fieldD = m.Groups["D"].Value;    // "15%"
string fieldE = m.Groups["E"].Value;    // "语言"
```

All fields are optional. If a field is not present, it will be captured as an empty string, like in `fieldC` above.

Comment: This will fail if some fields are missing.

Comment: @Nikolay: The original version would only have failed if Field A was missing. In the updated version, all fields are optional.

Answer (score 1):

```
/\s*(\d*)\s*([^\d\s]*)\s*(\d*)\s\s*(\d*%?)\s*([^\d\s]*)/
```

Here is a regex that will capture all of the content you want, use it on each line.

```
\s*         //any number of whitespace
(\d*)       //any number of digits
\s*         //any number of whitespace
([^\d\s]*)  //any number of characters that aren't whitespace or digits
\s*         //any number of whitespace
(\d*)\s     //any number of digits with a space after it
\s*         //any number of whitespace
(\d*%?)     //any number of digits with an optional %
\s*         //any number of whitespace
([^\d\s]*)  //any number of characters that aren't whitespace or digits
```